# Xamarin Sport App - Unknown Identifier

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I am looking at their sample application for sports leagues found here: https://github.com/xamarin/Sport

I put a breakpoint here:

[image]

But when I hover/do a quick watch on athleteId and/or registraitonComplete, I get

> Unknown identifier: Settings

The thing is, I can step into Settings so I know it can find it – heck it shouldn’t compile without it…

Comment: Thats just some IntelliSense error. If you put in the fully qualified name it should be able to find it. Doesn't make debugging easier however.

Comment: I don't think so.  I put the fully-qualified value into the QuickWatch and "Unknown Identifier" is still showing up

Comment: Hm anyhow, it's a IntelliSense issue nonetheless. If you do a 'Debug.WriteLine' or show it in an alert you see it will have a value

Answer (score 3):

No answers yet, here is the solution for those who are still looking for

Settings is a static class, somehow Visual studio(Xamarin) does not recognize the static class whose actual path and namespace does not match. So, to access Settings whose namespace is like below, you need to use `Sport.Mobile.Shared.Settings.`

```
namespace Sport.Mobile.Shared {
public static class Settings
```

This applies to any static class you use in your project.

Comment: It's so amazing that this simple workaround worked for me. In fact, I just used the fully-qualified object name.